# use different versions of php in nginx at the same time

Tags: php, nginx, config, fpm

i have 2 application: one written on php5.5, second on php8.0. When i tries setup separated php-cgi blocks in nginx - all requests handled by php5.5. Looks like php5.5 definition overrides php8.0 or idk

```
server
{
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name $NGINX_HOST;

  index index.php index.html;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  root /var/www/html;
  location ~ ^/reports
  {
    #root /var/www/html;
    alias /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri =404;
    location ~ \.php$
    {
      fastcgi_pass php8.0:9000;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }


  location /
  {
    alias /var/www/html/oldSystem;
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$
    {
      fastcgi_pass php5.5:9000;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

}
```

i'm tried use inherit locations, move locations and do other stuff without any effect

Comment: Did you tried to set full path to `php sock` file in `fastcgi_pass`?

Comment: i use different docker containers with php, so i use host-port instead. And yes, they pointed to different versions